Choose to resolve and report only some hypotheses
I have carried out a 2 x 2 x 4 x 4 experiment with 12 subjects to perform a linear mixed model. Would it be correct to perform the complete analysis but report only the results of the 2 x 2 interaction? Or should I average the results to perform a 2 x 2 LMM?
That is to say, the main hypothesis that we seek to resolve with the LMM is the 2 x 2 interaction, but the study was carried out as a 2 x 2 x 4 x 4 to fully analyze it with other statistical tests related to reliability.

What's wrong with reporting all results? You can still say that the 2x2 interaction is the main thing of interest.

The objective is to simplify the analysis and, above all, the writing of the results. This is a complex analysis with many interactions. Furthermore, these data will be analyzed from a reliability perspective later.

If you run a complex analysis and then don't give all results, that's not a "simplification" of the analysis as the analysis is already done when you write down the results. In the interest of scientific transparency I recommend to show all results. I assume that there were good reasons to include all these factors in the analysis, and if this is the case, full results are also of potential interest. Can't you put all results into a table that takes no more than a journal page, say?

Mandatory XKCD about not reporting all results

Think about it like this. Suppose you are a mechanic trying to fix a car. You decide that, based off previous intakes you have done, you will try Fix A, Fix B, and Fix C for this situation. After the work is done, the mechanic realizes that only Fix A works, and the other two do nothing to solve the problem. Should he conceal this information to himself, knowing only A works? Of course not. He should 1) retain this information so he can avoid going down this path again and 2) share this information with others so they don't make the same mistake.
One can think of theory as doing the same thing. We don't just report what we found "worked". We also need to tell the world what didn't. And even if it didn't this time, there is a chance that it works another time, where your study provides some accounting of which contexts it does work and which times it doesn't.
On a final note, if you anticipate that these interactions aren't going to amount to squat, why are you including them in the first place? Unless you have a specific theoretical reason for including them, then yes, in the interest of parsimony, one can reduce the model down before testing the model. Doing so post-hoc leads do dangerous outcomes like HARKing.

I add a little extra complexity. The Glimmpse sample size calculator for LLM with the full 2x2x4x4 model if I choose the 2x2x4x4 hypothesis, does not offer me enough power with my sample size, however with the full model if I choose the 2x2 hypothesis it does. Could this be a justification for reporting only the result for the 2x2 interaction?
On the other hand, it is curious, if in this calculator I enter the 2x2 model instead of the complete 2x2x4x4 model, when before it had enough power, now I don't have it. I understand that it could be another topic...

It is usually the case that interactions have less power, as they usually are not as strong as main effects. However, it seems you are using a post-hoc power justification, which isn't a good idea.

I am using the glimmpse calculator to calculate the sample size, but the sample offered for the 2x2x4x4 interaction is unattainable on a practical level. However if I choose the 2x2 interaction it would be achievable. Would this be a justification for choosing only 2x2?
The study must be carried out in a complete 2x2x4x4 manner because the 4x4 interaction will be analyzed from the perspective of reliability.

I re-read your question and this experiment was already conducted, so any power justifications that are made here are by definition post hoc and pointless.

Yes, I think then that I should carry out the 2x2 analysis because I do not have enough power to analyze 2x2x4x4 with this sample, which could lead to erroneous conclusions.

I do not understand how you would come to that conclusion based off what I said.

Power is a fundamental value to contextualize the conclusions, right?

And I just said that post-hoc power justifications for changing your design is pointless. From the link I already provided: "As the preceding explanation of post-hoc power hopefully illustrates, reporting post-hoc power is nothing more than reporting the p-value in a different way, and will therefore not answer the question editors want to know." The discussion would be different if we were talking about a priori power, but clearly that doesn't apply here.

ok, then I understand.
